# Custom Sorting Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, push

```
$original_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4); //<--- Original values without sorted.
$sorted_ids = array(4, 1, 3); //<--- Fixed values (sort by this)
$result_ids = array(); //<--- The result array after sorted
```

I just want to re-check matched array and sort by `$sorted_ids` (if you understand)

$result_ids must be... `array(4, 1, 3, 2)` ( **2** is not in $original_ids array so put it in **last**)

**I tied to code like... :**

```
foreach ($sorted_ids as &$id) {
    if (in_array($id , $original_ids)) {
        $result_ids[] = $id;
    } else {

    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to push no-matched arrays to last of the $result_ids array.

Comment if you don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result_ids = array_merge(
   array_intersect($sorted_ids, $original_ids),  // the values that match sorter
   array_diff($original_ids, $sorted_ids)        // append the rest
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($sorted_ids as $id) {
    if (in_array($id , $original_ids)) {
        $result_ids[] = $id;
    } else {
        $addToEnd[] = $id
    }
}

array_merge($result_ids, $addToEnd);
```

Your using of `&$id` is senseless btw, because you push it's value. You don't need a reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_merge($sorted_ids, array_diff($original_ids, $sorted_ids))
```

Comment: Note that this will also add values that are present in the sorter, but not in the original array

Comment: Uhh I didn't understand you, so you can use array_intersect within array_merge

Answer (score 0):

```
$original_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4); 
$sorted_ids = array(4, 1, 3);
foreach($original_ids as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($val,$sorted_ids)){
       unset($original_ids[$key]);
    }
}

$result_ids = array_merge($sorted_ids,$original_ids);

print_r($result_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
<?php

foreach ($sorted_ids as &$id) {
    if (sort($id)) {
        $result_ids[] = $id;
    } else {

    }
}

?>
```

it will do exactly what you need